# sed remove trailing slash from url

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to use sed to remove the trailing slash from urls. I can successfully remove a trailing slash using the following (please note it's in a build script in a package.json hence escaping quotes and double backslashes ).

```
"build": "sed -i -e 's/\\/\"/\"/g' index.html"
```

However, I'm worried this might be a bit over-zealous and I want to make sure this is only targeting urls with a href attribute, but I'm unsure how to make the BRE capture the url but not the final trailing slash. Basically I'm trying to use capture groups to accomplish this but I think now that is the problem with being too greedy. I've tried the following but then it doesn't seem to match anything:

```
"build": "sed -i -e 's/href=\"\\(.*\\)*\\/\"/href=\"\\1\"/g' index.html"
```

How could I go about doing this.

i.e
so href="https://example.com/path/foo/bar/"

becomes href="https://example.com/path/foo/bar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed accepts any delimiter for search and replace commands. So I recommend using e.g. `#` instead of slash to not confuse the delimiter with the search pattern.

To not be greedy, exclude the quotes from the joker list (`[^"]*`)

```
sed 's#href="\([^"]*\)/"#href="\1"#g' yourfile
```

should do the job

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use capture group with `sed`, you have to specify the `-r` option:

```
echo 'href="google.nl/"' | sed -r "s#href\=(\"|')([^'\"]*)/(\1)#href=\1\2\1#g"
```

The man page:

> -E, -r, --regexp-extended
>   use extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX -E).

Output of the regex:

```
href="google.nl/d" = href="google.nl/d"
href="google.nl"   = href="google.nl"
href="google.nl/"  = href="google.nl"
```

Comment: The capture group was working for me without the -r flag, in fact that flag caused the command to fail saying it was illegal (I'm running this on osx if that makes a difference)